# Yet another Python variable scope question

Tags: python, variables, scope

I have the following code:

```
>>> def f(v=1):
...     def ff():
...             print v
...             v = 2
...     ff()
...
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in ff
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v' referenced before assignment
```

I do understand why this message occurs ([Python variable scope question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question)), but how can I work with `v` variable in this case? `global v` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Why not just pass v to the ff() function?

Comment: @Rich for example there are can be multiple nested functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3.x, you can use [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement):

```
def f(v=1):
    def ff():
        nonlocal v
        print(v)
        v = 2
    ff()
```

In Python 2.x, there is no easy solution.  A hack is to make `v` a list:

```
def f(v=None):
    if v is None:
        v = [1]
    def ff():
        print v[0]
        v[0] = 2
    ff()
```

Comment: Note that the second falls to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument (calling it a second time without providing `v` prints 2).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't passed v to the inner function ff.  It creates its own scope when you declare it.  This should work in python 2.x:

```
def f(v=1):
  def ff(v=1):
    print v
    v = 2
  ff(v)
```

But the assignment call to `v = 2` would not be persistent in other calls to the function.

Comment: Perhaps `def ff(v=v)` would come closer to what the OP wants.